# What is referred to as 'strong drink' which John the Baptist was restrained from drinking in Lk 1:15?

Tags: luke, john-the-baptist

We read in Luke 1:13-15 (NRSVCE) of the Angel foretelling the birth of John the Baptist:

> “Do not be afraid, Zechariah, for your prayer has been heard. Your wife Elizabeth will bear you a son, and you will name him John. You will have joy and gladness, and many will rejoice at his birth, for he will be great in the sight of the Lord. He must never drink wine or strong drink.."

Of course, John as an adult, led an ascetic life and survived on   locusts and wild honey (Mtt 3:4). He must also have abstained from drinking wine of the grape, as had been stipulated by the Angel. But a doubt remains as to what was referred to by 'strong drink' by the Angel. In ancient civilizations where grape was not cultivated, intoxicating drinks from other fruits, flowers or food grains used to be made. It is not clear if there were drinks (like coffee and tea) which were regarded as strong but not intoxicating.

My question, therefore, is: What is referred to as 'strong drink' which John the Baptist was restrained from drinking in Lk 1:15?

Comment: related:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/was-john-the-baptist-a-nazirite

Comment: Certainly not a complete answer, thus the comment: coffee had not yet been invented at this time, so we can easily rule that out. While the exact date of coffee's discovery is disputed, 700 AD is usually given as the earliest possible date.

Comment: And since distillation of alcohol (at least as we know it today) wasn't invented till the 8th or 9th century (https://www.whiskeystill.net/blogs/whiskey-still-co-blog/16341160-the-distillation-of-alcohol-a-brief-history) it also seems likely that "strong drink" doesn't refer to distilled alcohols.

Answer (score 7):

In Luke 1:15, "strong drink" is the translation of a single Greek word, σίκερα (sikera), a hapex legomenon which BDAG defines as:

> ... **an alcoholic beverage**. As a rule σίκερα was differentiated
> from wine and mentioned with it (Lev 10:9, Num 6:3, Deut 29:5, Isa 29:9) ... it
> is not possible to determine whether σίκερα was considered stronger
> than wine; the rendering 'strong drink' (so in many versions) may
> therefore be misleading

That is, there is no compelling evidence as to what σίκερα was other than it was an alcoholic drink.

All that can be said is that John the Baptist was a Nazirite from birth and thus unable to imbibe of any product of the grape and alcoholic drinks.  See Num 6:3, 4.  Compare Samson in Judges 13:4, 5.

---

NOTE: The fact that σίκερα was an alcoholic drink means that cannot have been coffee or tea, etc.  In any case, these beverages were unknown in first century Roman empire.

Comment: + 1  -  I suggest Nazirite rather than Nazarene, as the latter is used to describe where Jesus was from, not the Nazirite tradition.

Comment: To expand a little: it seems that *σίκερα* arose as a hapax legomenon in the Bible because it was a transcription of the Hebrew *shekar*, *shakar*, which are more widely attested as meaning respectively “some kind of strong drink” and “drunken/intoxicated”.  Strong’s Concordance: [H7941](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h7941/wlc/wlc/0-1/), [H7937](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h7937/wlc/wlc/0-1/)

Comment: @DanFefferman - my apologies - I will correct this stupid mistake,

Answer (score 5):

I asked the question of what is being referred to as **['strong drink' at the time of St John the Baptist](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/6686/strong-drink-at-the-time-of-st-john-the-baptist/)** on [Beer, Wine, & Spirits Stack Exchange](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/).

And noting that St John the Baptist never drank wine or strong drink.

For he shall be great in the sight of the Lord, and shall drink neither wine nor strong drink; and he shall be filled with the Holy Ghost, even from his mother's womb. - Luke 1:15 (KJV)

The user [Socrates](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/6568/socrates) gave [an answer](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/a/6689) to my question that examined the passage in the original Greek:

> > ἔσται γὰρ μέγας ἐνώπιον τοῦ Κυρίου, καὶ οἶνον καὶ σίκερα οὐ μὴ πίῃ, καὶ Πνεύματος Ἁγίου πλησθήσεται ἔτι ἐκ κοιλίας μητρὸς αὐτοῦ.
>
> The two words we are intereted in here are 'οἶνον' ('wine'), and 'σίκερα' ('strong drink'). The second ('σίκερα') is interesting in that it is a loan word directly from the Hebrew word 'שכר' (transliterated 'shekar'). This word is rather popular in the Old Testamant (appearing 7941 times), so it is little surprise that 'σίκερα' appears in the New Testament. The two (in both languages) are usually used in conjunction with each other, to form the phrase 'wine and strong drink' to encompass the whole variety of intoxicants. [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_in_the_Bible#Hebrew)
>
> **The Wine**
>
> Wine was the ubiquitous alcoholic beverage of the ancient world. The process by which the ancient peoples made wine was simple. First, they pressed grapes into grape juice, then left the juice in large earthenware jars to ferment. Fermentation took two weeks to a month. Distillation had not yet been discovered, so Roman wine was of about the same strength as modern wine (around 13%), or possibly a bit stronger.
>
> While 'true' Romans diluted their wine with water (roughly one part wine to two parts water), making it a beverage that could be drunk all day long, without danger of drunkenness, people living in provinces, such as Judea, are not supposed to have done so. That said, it is likely that the Roman officials did dilute their wine, in keeping with the custom back in Rome. Because of this, it is also likely that citizens wishing to curry their favour might also have adopted this custom. The Greeks also diluted their wine (roughly one part wine to four parts water). [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_alcoholic_drinks#Rome)
>
> **Other Alcohols**
>
> Other alcohols included beer, which became significantly less popular than wine. In particular, wealthy Romans looked down on the drinking of beer. Tacitus (writing much later, in the 1st Century AD) wrote disparagingly of German beer. Barley wine (a type of strong ale, roughly 6-11%) existed, as well as alcohols made from whatever fruits might be growing in the vicinity. For example, when Caesar arrived in Britain in 55BC, he found the locals drinking an apple cider, a custom he and his men adopted with enthusiasm. [[3]](http://drinkfocus.com/beer/history-of-apple-cider/)
>
> I have not be able to find any evidence for the consumption of distilled spirits or liqueurs.

Comment: Note: The numbers 7941 and 4608 are not occurrence counts; they are the ID numbers assigned to the words by Strong's Concordance. The linked Wikipedia page says 'שכר' appears in the Bible 23 times and 'σίκερα' appears only once. (I've also posted a comment to that effect on the answer you're citing.)

Comment: Thanks, Ken Graham. By asking the question on BW&SSE, did you not unwittingly admit that `strong drink 'refers to intoxicating drink ? By the way,  there is a preparation  called Kahwa  in the orient. It  is a mixture of dry fruits, nuts and saffron in boiled water, with or without tea leaf.  It in deed is a strong drink, especially suitable for winter days.

Answer (score 4):

***The NIV uses the expression “fermented drink” in Luke 1:15.***  Luke 7:33 simply states that “John the Baptist came neither eating bread nor drinking wine.”

The Old Testament makes references to the Levitical priests and Nazirites abstaining from wine and other fermented drinks:

> If a man or woman wants to make a special vow, a vow of separation to the LORD as a Nazirite, he must abstain from wine and other fermented drink and must not drink vinegar made from wine or from other fermented drink.  He must not drink grape juice or eat grapes or rasins.  As long as he is a Nazirite, he must not eat anything that comes from the grapevine, not even the seeds or skins (Numbers 6:1-4).

> You and your sons are not to drink wine or other fermented drink whenever you go into the Tent of Meeting, or you will die.  This is a lasting ordinance for the generations to come (Leviticus 10:9).

Fermentation is a metabolic process in which an organism converts a carbohydrate, such as starch or a sugar, into an alcohol or an acid.  Beer and wine are produced by fermenting glucose with yeast. Yeast contains enzymes that catalyse the breakdown of glucose to ethanol and carbon dioxide. The use of fermentation, particularly for beverages, has existed since the Neolithic and has been documented dating from 7000 to 6600 BCE.

Fermented drinks were not confined to wine, although that was the common beverage during Roman times. Honey was added to sweeten wine, producing a popular beverage called [mulsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulsum_(beverage)). Spices and medicinal herbs were also added to bolster its purported medical qualities.

In the ancient Mediterranean world, the Cult of Dionysus and the Orphic mysteries used wine as part of their religious practices. During Dionysian festivals and rituals, wine was drunk as way to reach ecstatic states along with music and dance. Intoxication from alcohol was seen as a state of possession by spirit of the god of wine Dionysus. Religious drinking festivals called Bacchanalia were popular in Italy and associated with the gods Bacchus and Liber. These Dionysian rites were frequently outlawed by the Roman Senate. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_and_alcohol#:~:text=Intoxication%20from%20alcohol%20was%20seen,outlawed%20by%20the%20Roman%20Senate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_and_alcohol#:%7E:text=Intoxication%20from%20alcohol%20was%20seen,outlawed%20by%20the%20Roman%20Senate).

Comment: So based upon fermented drink... various vinegars and buttermilks like leben as well? (If they were drank in the society at that time? ... I know the Gospels mention vinegar being given Jesus on the cross) Could imagine it as one of those times various translations give words that wind up misleading, so interested to see more investigation of the original word rather than just a look at translations :) Probably not the biggest importance on this question, but seems to remind of the potential errs or even danger of drawing too many conclusions from any translation intellectually (even KJV)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest My answer was posted before the question was moved from Christianity Stack Exchange to Biblical Hermeneutics. Please refer to Dottard's answer which deals with the translation from Greek into English, an answer I have upvoted.  I am not a Greek scholar but it's clear that whether "strong drink" or "fermented drink" is the English translation given, it means an alcoholic drink that results in being intoxicated.